# Makefile script not building the python project zip properly

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, makefile, terraform, gitlab

I have below the `Makefile` script inside a `docker container` that executes a few commands for building the zip of the project and then initializes the terraform directory and uploads it in AWS. However, the zip which is uploaded for the lambda function raises a `module not found` error. Below is my script:

```
run : build_and_deploy

build_and_deploy : 
    apt-get update && apt-get install zip; \
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip; \
    cd provisioner && pip install . --target=dependencies && cd dependencies && zip -r ../snp.zip . && cd ..  && cd src && zip -r ../snp.zip . && cd .. && cd .. ; \
    cd iac && terraform init -backend-config="bucket=some-state-8435202378" -backend-config="key=state/278435202378/somename.somedev.tfstate" -backend-config="region=eu-west-1" && terraform apply -auto-approve -var "environment=dev" -var "lambda_file=../provisioner/snp.zip" -var "lambda_handler=common.api.lambda_handler.lambda_handler" -var "domain_name=specific-snp-dev.dev.boot.com" -var "truststore_pem=${TRUSTSTORE_PEM}" -var "aws_route53_zone_name=dev.boot.com" -var 'tags={scope="boot.snowflake.specific.provisioner", alwaysOn=true, ownedBy="somename.Snowflake.SnowflakeSpecificProvisioner", createdBy="somename.Snowflake.SnowflakeSpecificProvisioner"}'; \

clean :
    rm -rf __pycache__
```

When I try to deploy the project why gitlab pipeline using the same commands, it works fine. I don't get any errors. I am running this script on the docker container. I am getting the below error:

```
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'common.api.lambda_handler': /var/task/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}
```

Comment: There's no way to help with the information given.  Paraphrasing error messages down to a few words is not sufficient for us to know what's wrong.  Please edit your question and cut and paste the exact command you typed and most importantly the complete error messages you got.

Comment: @MadScientist I have modified the code and pasted the error message. I hope this helps!

Comment: This seems like it is much more a Lambda or Terraform question than it is a Make question - you're not really making use of any Make features. I'd suggest simplifying the `build_and_deploy` target down to a shell script so that a broader audience can understand it, and tagging with [tag:aws-lambda] and [tag:terraform].

Comment: @NickODell When I run the same commands via the gitlab pipeline it works fine and when I converted the pipeline into the `make file` it gave me this error. Not sure if there are any edge cases that I am missing here.

Comment: The error indicates that it failed to find the shared library `/var/task/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so` when running inside the pipeline.  So you need to figure out why that's not present there.

Comment: Every command worked fine. Do you think I am missing something w.r.t makefile or best practices?

Comment: Make doesn't do anything special: it just runs commands.  It does use a POSIX shell to run them, so it doesn't see things like shell functions or aliases.  But if it works when you do it from the command line but not from within a makefile, then something about your environment that is needed, is not being translated into the makefile

Comment: Yeah, I think something has to do with the docker image. I will try changing the image.